# split 10 e-mails from an e-mail list with 30, from 10 to 10 with

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a list of e-mails in my query, with more than 30 e-mails.

```
Print @Emails
```

> Result: email1[a]test.com; email2[a]test.com; ... ; email35[a]test.com;

I need to send from 10 to 10. I have to take 10 from this list to send.

How can this be done with SQL Server?

Comment: I surgest you reveal more details for this question

Answer (score 0):

Try this sql, it uses Common Table Expressions(CTE) to loop throught the input value, there are other methods available but this should meet your needs if you wish to break up a string input and convert it to a table:

```
DECLARE @DemoTable table (Layout varchar(2000)) 
INSERT @DemoTable VALUES ('email1[a]test.com;email2[a]test.com;email3[a]test.com;email4[a]test.com;email5[a]test.com;email6[a]test.com;email7[a]test.com;email8[a]test.com;email9[a]test.com;email10[a]test.com;email11[a]test.com;email12[a]test.com;email13[a]test.com;email14[a]test.com;email15[a]test.com;email16[a]test.com;email17[a]test.com;email18[a]test.com;email19[a]test.com;email20[a]test.com;email21[a]test.com;email22[a]test.com;email23[a]test.com;email24[a]test.com;email25[a]test.com;email26[a]test.com;email27[a]test.com;email28[a]test.com;email29[a]test.com;email30[a]test.com;email31[a]test.com;email32[a]test.com;email33[a]test.com;email34[a]test.com;email35[a]test.com;') 

DECLARE @StringToTable table (email varchar(200)) 
DECLARE @Concatenated VARCHAR(2000)
SET @Concatenated=''
;WITH StringToTable AS 
(   SELECT LEFT(Layout,CHARINDEX(';',Layout)) AS Email 
        ,  RIGHT(Layout,LEN(Layout)-CHARINDEX(';',Layout)) StringToProcess 
    FROM @DemoTable 
    WHERE Layout IS NOT NULL AND CHARINDEX(';',Layout)>0 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT LEFT(StringToProcess,CHARINDEX(';',StringToProcess)) 
        ,  RIGHT(StringToProcess,LEN(StringToProcess)-CHARINDEX(';',StringToProcess)) 
    FROM StringToTable 
    WHERE StringToProcess IS NOT NULL AND CHARINDEX(';',StringToProcess)>0 
) 
INSERT INTO @StringToTable(email)
SELECT TOP 10 Email FROM StringToTable--TOP 10 is to get the 10 mentioned in the question - you can change the order by to affect which 10 you wish to use.

SELECT Email  FROM @StringToTable
```

If you need to reintegrate the rows into a string you can do it like this:

```
SELECT @Concatenated = @Concatenated + Email  FROM @StringToTable

SELECT @Concatenated
```